# Magento2 Subscription Error not showing

Tags: error, newsletter, magento2.2.4

I am using default Magento2.2.4. The subscription is working correctly. But when I am entering an email again, it is not showing any error. 
So if I enter test@test.com then I am getting subscribed in the list in admin. Which is correct. But if I enter the same email a second time, I am still getting success message, but ideally there should be a message that you are already subscribed.

Can someone help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the below in my controller constructor-

```
\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber,
```

Earlier I was using the Factory, but not sure why it was not working correctly. So I can using this and a work around

```
$checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($email); 
                    if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
                        $response = [
                            'status' => 'ERROR',
                            'msg' => __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'),
                        ];                        

                    }
```